# How to get five last few (5) items from database in the Vb

Tags: mysql, vb.net

How to get the last few data records from the database in VB.Net?

Answer (score 0):

Is there an auto incremented column in the table?

You could do something like

```
SELECT TOP 5 *
FROM [table_name]
ORDER BY [auto_incremented primary key] DESC
```

Which will sort the primary key in descending order and return the first (last) 5 entries (or however many you want).

Comment: You could also order by a date field decending if you have a field that contains the date the record was created (or if relevant updated...) that would give you the oldest 5 records.